A Train Robbery
I've looking for this movie: (I think its a famous classical movie but when I Google it, the words are so common that I can't find anything relevant)
The movie is about a robbery in a train, for a security box. The thieves use some kind of wax or soup to duplicate the keys. The train is a an old train (but I don't know if its electrical or steam), oriented in the end of the 19th century (1890s maybe).
I just remember a few scenes. I remember a white-haired wise old man as Master-chief of the robbery plan or something like that.

Could it be Michael Crichton's The Great Train Robbery (also called The First Great Train Robbery)? From Wikipedia:

To ensure the success of his plan, Pierce plans out the robbery in
  explicit detail, and even procures information on the security
  measures and locations of the keys. The executives of the bank who
  store the gold and arrange its transport, Mr. Henry Fowler and Mr.
  Edgar Trent, each possess a key; the other two are locked in a cabinet
  at the offices of the South Eastern Railway at the London Bridge train
  station. The keys are not to be stolen, but wax copies are to be made
  of them in order to hide the robbers' intentions.

More info: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079240/

I don't remember that was with Sean Connery but I think you are right. I'll see it! Thanks a lot and sorry for my english
